# Binding ng-model directive and value attribute with same property for text box made the chinese character to erase

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to bind ng-model and value attribute with sameproperty. Its work fine in all browsers. But in IE8, when i used chinese input, it gets auto clear when typing. This happens only if ng-model and value attribute binded with same attribute.

Here is the sample code

```
<html ng-app="dummy">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
     <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <title>Angular</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var countryApp = angular.module('dummy',[]);

        countryApp.controller('dummyCtrl',['$scope',function(scope){
            scope.dummyVar = '1';               
        }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="dummyCtrl">
        <input ng-model="dummyVar" value="{{dummyVar}}"/>
        <p>{{dummyVar}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove : `value="{{dummyVar}}`ng-model will put the initial value of your model to input. And input changes will change value on model

```
<div ng-controller="dummyCtrl">
    <input ng-model="dummyVar"/>
    <p>{{dummyVar}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks... I already suggested that to my team.But the think is, i need to keep the value attribute. And also i suggested to change the property for value attribute. But they need why it is happening?

Comment: You don't need to set the value at all. ng-model takes care of it is not correct binding. read documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D